# Intel Celeron N3350 1100 МГц как его заставить работать на максимальной частоте 2.4ггц?

Tags: intel

Intel Celeron N3350 1100 МГц в описании указано up to 2.4ghz но функции турбо буст он не поддерживает.

Comment: Это должен поддерживать также биос в материнке.

Comment: Для разгона нужны дорогие материнка, блок питания, память, кулер. Проще пойти на работу, заработать денег и купить новый более быстрый проц.

Answer (score 1):

Частрота работы процессора задается двумя параметрами: частотой шины и множителем. Соовтетственно существует 2 пути разгона: поднять частоту системной шины или увеличить множитель. Для этого существуют специальные настройки в BIOS, днако у Intel есть технология [Torbo Boos](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Boost), которая позволяет увеличеть частоту процесса при нагрузках. Вообще Intel позволяет гнать только процессоры с индексом K на топовых чипсетах. Согласно [спецификации](https://ark.intel.com/ru/products/95598/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N3350-2M-Cache-up-to-2-4-GHz-) этот проц не поддерживает Terbo Boost, но в некоторых ревизиях может работать на частоте до 2,4 Ггц хотя его базовая частота 1,1 Ггц

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в описании процессора "up to 2.4ghz" имеется в виду, что при нагрузке только на одно ядро оно получает больше питания (за счет второго неактивного) и работает на более высоких частотах.

Вы можете в CPU-Z запустить CPU Single Thread во вкладке Bench и проверить поднимется ли частота у активного ядра.